# Too many select calls to database for linq Many-To-Many join table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

My problem is for a complex database so I have used a simplified version below.

I have 3 tables. Lets call them:

```
Course
    - id
    - name

Student
    - id
    - name

StudentCourses
    - id
    - student_id
    - course_id
```

StudentCourses is set to relate to both the other tables, a fairly normal many-to-many pattern.

I have extended my Student object using partials, and added a fairly basic method to my Student class in order to retrieve all of their classes.

```
// Partial to add helper method to LINQ generated Student class
public partial class Student {

    // Get courses that this student is enrolled.
    public IQueryable<Course> GetCourses(){
        return this.StudentCourses.Select(d=>d.Course);
    }
}
```

I expected this might use a join internally, but having logged the SQL queries I can see that it actually makes one "SELECT * FROM Courses" for each join.

What would be a better way to perform this behaviour? One select per row seems terribly inefficient!

**Further Investigation**
After a few comments I decided to investigate further. I have found the following:

```
MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
var student = db.Students.Single(i=>i.id);

var testOne = db.StudentCourses.Where(u=>u.student_id == student.id).
                                      Select(d=>d.Courses).ToList();

var testTwo = student.StudentCourses.Select(d=>d.Courses).ToList();
```

In test one, the SQL performed uses a JOIN and is therefore a single database call.
In test two, the SQL is one select PER course. Which is a problem.

Is this just expected behaviour? I can refactor to the first type I guess, but I prefer the logic of the second test.

Comment: You need to put your code in a little bit more context, how and where do you call `this.StudentCourses.Select(d=>d.Course);`?

Comment: It is in a partial which I added to the Student class; as described above. I've edited in a little more context.

Comment: But where do you call the GetCourses-method?

Comment: In wider scope I use the Repository pattern, so there I get a Student object using StudentRepository, then once I have a student object I can call the GetCourses method.

I don't see how the place I call the code from is relevant to the issue at hand?

Comment: Do you have an actual performance issue with this current code?

Comment: Not really, but it seems bad practise.

Comment: @KingCronus - Thanks for the update, but I would still like to know if there is an actual performance issue? Do you have an actual scenario where the select-per-course actually is too slow in practice?

Comment: It is a scalability problem. This example is very simplified, in reality I have potentially got 500 students, each who will have 20+ courses. By using DataLoadOptions what would have been 20 database hits has now been reduced to 2. Times this by 500 and you can see that it makes quite a difference. My database and application servers are located in different locations so I want to keep round trips to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For LinqToSql use **[DataLoadOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.dataloadoptions.aspx)**

**Example :**

```
public IQueryable<Course> GetCourses(){
    var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
    dlo.LoadWith<StudentCourses>(d => d.Course);
    this.LoadOptions = dlo;

    return this.GetTable<StudentCourses>().Select(d=>d.Course);
}
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Include isn't a part of Linq-to-Sql to my knowledge. Are you confusing my question with EF?

Comment: Fantastic! I've managed to get it working through a combination of this post and this website: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37857/Optimizing-LINQ-Queries-using-DataLoadOptions